# flask redirect not working

Tags: python, flask

I'm using flask. Here's my login function:

```
@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def login():
if request.method == "POST" and "imei" in request.form and "password" in request.form:
    imei = request.form["imei"]
    password = request.form["password"]
    worked, name = checkDB(imei, password)
    if worked:
        uid = hashlib.sha256(imei.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
        u = User(imei, name, password, uid)
        USERS[uid] = u
        login_user(u)
        #return request.args.get("next")
        return redirect(url_for("analyzer")) #THIS DOESENT WORK
    else:
        return redirect(url_for("login") + "?failure=true")
elif request.method == "GET" and request.args.get("failure"):    
    return render_template("auth.html", fail="true")
else:
    return render_template("auth.html", fail="false")
```

When the line attempts to trigger (the one labeled THIS DOESENT WORK), it redirects to: `/?next=%2Fwebike%2Fanalyzer`.

The analyzer is simple:

```
@app.route('/analyzer', methods=['GET'])
@login_required
def analyzer():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

What am I doing wrong? If the username and password are wrong, everything works as intended.

Comment: What does `u.get_id()` return?

Comment: where would you like to see this run, right after `login_user`?

Comment: After `u = User(imei, name, password, uid)`.

Comment: After I do login_user(u), printing `u` prints `<User.User object at 0x7f626c5f1c88>` and printing `u.get_id()` prints `4bff3b8da1bd7ba81a0de577f62a011ed9b446093e649052664004e972461a92
` which is correct.

Comment: Is that user in the database?

Comment: What exaclty do you mean by database? The `checkDB` function actually goes out and verifies the credentials in the MySQL user database. Everything inside the function you see above only triggers if that results in a `True`. As far as the current Flask users logged in, I'm simply using a dictionary called `USERS`.

Comment: How is `USERS` defined? Are you running your application using Flask's development server or are you running it through something like uWSGI or gunicorn?

Comment: USERS is just a dictionary that gets instantiated at the top of this file. I am running it through WSGI.

Comment: Now you made me think of something! I am using `g.stuff` (`from flask import g`) for other things. Do I need to use this Flask globals class for this users dictionary??

Comment: The `USERS` dictionary won't be shared across processes. If your log in request is handled by one process and then the `/analyzer` request is handled by another, `user_loader` will fail to find `USERS['4bff3b8da1bd7ba81a0de577f62a011ed9b446093e649052664004e972461a92']`.

Comment: `g` is rebuilt for each new request, `g.USERS` would be empty unless you repopulated the dictionary at the beginning of each request.

Answer (score 0):

The login didn't work properly. You successfully redirect to `/analyzer`, but that redirects back to your login method because of the `@login_required` decorator, appending the analyzer method url as the `next` parameter.

```
u = User(imei, name, password, uid)
```

Here, you're not performing a lookup, you're making a new User object. Instead of making a new object, you'll need to get the User from your database and pass *that* to the `login_user` method. [Documentation for the method here](https://flask-login.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#flask.ext.login.login_user).

Comment: That method says `Logs a user in. You should pass the actual user object to this`. But I am passing the actual user object. What am I doping wrong?

Comment: "Here, you're not performing a lookup, you're making a new User object. Instead of making a new object, you'll need to get the User from your database and pass that to the login_user method." See [this exmaple](http://flask-login.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#custom-login-using-request-loader).

Comment: `login_user(u)` DOES pass the `actual user object`, because `u` IS the actual user object.